# SP13: Changing Edit Icon

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, css

I am sure this is possible, however, not sure if this is an out of the box fix.

Goal: To remove the edit icon ( [image])and add the word "edit"

Is there an out of box solution?

Comment: Where is the Edit icon you want to get rid of? Ribbon?

Comment: Sorry @MikeLutge I was not clear.  It's the edit icon that appears on a custom list or document library.  It has the paper with the pencil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following css to hide the icon and insert "Edit" text.

```
.ms-listviewtable .ms-cellstyle.ms-vb-icon > .ms-draggable IMG[src*="edititem.gif"]{
    display:none;
}
.ms-listviewtable .ms-cellstyle.ms-vb-icon > .ms-draggable:after{
    content:'Edit';
}
```

The trouble with this is that the edit column doesn't seem to have any css classes that are totally specific to it. So you wouldn't want to add this code globally to a masterpage or similar. But you might be able to get away with it if you just added it to a CEWP on the list page you want to alter.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to trying to change the default edit column is make your own. You can use a calculated column and style the link however you want (including by making it look like a button).

Create a calculated column and set datatype to number. This will allow you to run code in the column.
An example below should be all you need to make a edit link that takes you to the edit form.

```
="<a href='http://Site/etc..'& [ID]>EDIT</a>"
```

Down side is that it is not automatically set to your default edit form.

Also, this method will break link in the edit the button after editing because the ID field is not supported in calculated columns, and it will not work for new items.